# Apache returns same site from two domains

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost

I'm having an issue with apache that I just can't seem to fix.

I have two domains which point to two different DocumentRoot's in the Virtual Host file. However, I can't get that to work properly, the site that I was trying to add wouldn't show from the second domain at all, but it would instead show the first site (as far as I know this is the default and it means something is wrong with my second virtual host).

I managed to curcumvent this issue by putting my new website before the first virtual Host. This meant that the new website showed, but was put into a `frameset` tag by apache and I was unable to control the header.

Running Apache 2.2.22 on Raspbian (Debian Linux)

Heres my current code;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName DIR0.com
ServerAlias www.DIR0.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/DIR0.com/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/DIR0.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errors_DIR0.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_DIR0.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName DIR1.com
    ServerAlias www.DIR1.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/DIR1/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/DIR1.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_DIR1.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_DIR1.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: RPis are not topical on serverfault. Browse the [tag:virtualhost] for clues.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have set

> NameVirtualHost *:80

in your config file. This directive enables the use of ServerName as identification of VirtualHost. If this is missing, you're using IP/port for identification of VirtualHost, which is same for both of those VirtualHost.

Comment: Beat me to it!

This is needed to tell apache to use ServerName as the host identifier.

Comment: Putting `NameVirtualHost *:80` at the top of the file gives the following error when I restart apache `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Comment: What is the result of the command `Apachectl -S` ?